# migrate mysql database to oracle 9i

Tags: mysql, oracle

I need suggestion on how to  migrate schema from Mysql to oracle 9i database

I made google search but there is really few info about migration to oracle 9i since it is very old 
but it is business requirement from now that ca not be change so

I need suggestion from experienced people with same issue

thanks

Comment: what business requirement can make you choose to migrate a database to an unsupported version since 2005 ?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO sadly yes the migration should be to oracle 9i which is up and running

Comment: Are you sure it's Oracle 9? That's long obsolete. We are in Oracle 19 now...

Comment: @TheImpaler yes i am sure sadly

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use mysqldump with the parameter compatible=ansi:

```
mysqldump --compatible=ansi --complete-insert --compact --default-character-set=latin1 --no-create-info --no-create-db --extended-insert=0 --skip-quote-names
```

You may want to review the parameters to be sure they fit yours.

Comment: I got an error says `Invalid mode to --compatible: oracle`

Comment: which version of mysql are you running ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: use --compatible=ansi the option changed in the newer version of mysql